# How to store cleaned and raw data in a database?

Tags: database, data-cleaning

A raw data is stored in a database (multiple tables). it needs to be manually checked and corrected. The checked data should be stored in database along with the raw data as well. In that case, will it be good idea to create two separate databases (eg. raw_data and checked_data) ? Or there should be only one database?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking it is a lot easier to work within a single instance than across multiple instances.  Distributed transactions perform slower.  They require more typing (always having to add a database link).  This is not just a matter of convenience but also of integrity.   You may want to ensure that a given record is either in the RAW data set or the CLEANSED data set but not both.  Checking this sort of thing is more manageable in a single database.

How you organize things in a single database depends to some extent on your chosen DBMS flavour, and what it supports.  You can have a single schema (user account) and use a naming convention such as prefix, for example RAW_TABLE_1 and CLEAN_TABLE_1.  Or you may want to use different schemas, which will allow you to retain the same table name, for example RAW_USER.TABLE_1 and CLEAN_USER.TABLE_1.  Both approaches have advantages.  It is always good to have a constant reminder of whether we are working with raw or clean data.  On the other hand we may have tools or applications which we would like to use that expect the normal table names.  Synonyms can help in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

If your raw data and checked data are going to be very inormous than only use two different database

With **normalization** and using procedures you can maintain it in one database.

Answer (score 0):

There is no recommended method here except your own preferences. You can store the cleansed data with raw data in same database but in different tables and may be prefix something like raw_ to the raw data tables.

Otherwise you may have a seperate database for each type of data. The benefits would be seperation where as the drawback would be costlier Join etc if need to be done between these two.